# Insert Images Based On Meta Data For Product Rating

Tags: php

I'm working on a search results page for my hobbyist website that displays basic product information from the SQL dB. Each product has a rating from 1-10. I'm looking to implement a star rating based on the stored meta.

Currently my query displays the rating as "3/10"

I would like to display a star rating rather than the plain text "3/10". If a product had a 4 star rating, 4 gold stars would appear while the other 6 remained dark. If the product was rated 10/10, all 10 stars would be gold.

Comment: Could you rephrase your question to make it specific what you are asking?

Comment: Sorry, maybe I wasn't clear enough. I'm essentially trying to generate an image based off the results from my "product rating" query. If the rating is 1 out of 10, this image appears, while a different image appears if the rating is 2 out of 10.. so on

Comment: And what in specific is the problem?

Answer (score 2):

In PHP get the rating out of 10: 3/10, get the 3 and store it into a variable. 
So if this is coming from a query, which I'm assuming it is, and if it is stored as "3/10". You can just `explode("/", $row['rating']);` which is an array and just select the first value for the score.

```
For($i=0; $i <= $score; $i++){
    echo "<img src='images/star.jpg' />";
}
```

Comment: Awesome. Definitely beyond my scope of knowledge at this point, but now I know which verbiage I'm looking for. Thank you!

Comment: You're very welcome. I tried not to do the whole code, but I think you have everything you need there to learn some stuff. Good luck and don't hesitate to ask more questions if you need to.

Comment: Alright, it's halfway working. I have an image inserted for a value, but it's appearing multiple times (looks like 10 times for each) rather than just once. It's almost like the variable isn't being read correctly. Any idea if I need to clean something up to fix this? The code is as follows.

 `<?php $rating = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'product_rating', true ); ?>


<?php For($i=1.0; $i <= $rating; $i++){
    echo "<img src='http://www.domain.com/lpimage/lock50.png' />";
}
?>`

Comment: That's rather odd, what you could do for testing is just echo out the `$rating` to see what it's storing. Also, you shouldn't use a float: `for($i=1.0...)` start from 0 and keep it as a plain integer for what you need.